# \part seems doesn't use \cleardoublepage

Tags: parts

I redefined the `\cleardoublepage` to show "This page is intentionally left blank". However when using `\part` command, it produce an empty page not the same as defined in `\cleardoublepage`. Why is this happening?

Below is a MWE.

```
\documentclass[10pt]{book}

\usepackage{tikz}
\makeatletter
\renewcommand{\cleardoublepage}{\relax
  \clearpage
  \if@twoside \ifodd\c@page\relax\else
  \thispagestyle{empty}%
  \tikz[remember picture, overlay] \node at (current page.center)
    {\large This page is intentionally left blank};\newpage\fi\fi}
\makeatother

\usepackage{blindtext}

\begin{document}
\part{Some title}
\chapter{Name}
\blindtext
\chapter{Other Name}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Correct; `\part` doesn't issue a `\cleardoublepage`. Here is the definitions associated with `\part` taken from [`book.cls`](https://www.tug.org/svn/texlive/trunk/Master/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/book.cls?view=co):

```
\newcommand\part{%
  \if@openright
    \cleardoublepage
  \else
    \clearpage
  \fi
  \thispagestyle{plain}%
  \if@twocolumn
    \onecolumn
    \@tempswatrue
  \else
    \@tempswafalse
  \fi
  \null\vfil
  \secdef\@part\@spart}

\def\@part[#1]#2{%
    \ifnum \c@secnumdepth >-2\relax
      \refstepcounter{part}%
      \addcontentsline{toc}{part}{\thepart\hspace{1em}#1}%
    \else
      \addcontentsline{toc}{part}{#1}%
    \fi
    \markboth{}{}%
    {\centering
     \interlinepenalty \@M
     \normalfont
     \ifnum \c@secnumdepth >-2\relax
       \huge\bfseries \partname\nobreakspace\thepart
       \par
       \vskip 20\p@
     \fi
     \Huge \bfseries #2\par}%
    \@endpart}
\def\@spart#1{%
    {\centering
     \interlinepenalty \@M
     \normalfont
     \Huge \bfseries #1\par}%
    \@endpart}
\def\@endpart{\vfil\newpage
              \if@twoside
               \if@openright
                \null
                \thispagestyle{empty}%
                \newpage
               \fi
              \fi
              \if@tempswa
                \twocolumn
              \fi}
```

Note how `\part` uses either `\@part` or `\@spart` depending on whether you use `\part` or `\part*`, yet both end with `\@endpart`. And, there's not `\cleardoublepage` within `\@endpart`. With your elementary setup, it suffices to redefine `\@endpart` to

```
\def\@endpart{\vfil\cleardoublepage}
```

[image]